# images from matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have written a matlab code which would load the matrix written in a text file and then I want to show it as an image. The text file contains integers number from 0 to 2 in a random fashion and I want to represent each in a different colors e.g. 0 in white,1 in some color and 2 in a different color. I would provide the matlab code just below :

```
clc;
clear all;

for i=1:10
 k=num2str(i);
 f = strcat('test_file_num_',k,'.txt');
 a{i} = fileread(f);

 [m,n] = size(a{i});

 a{i} = reshape(a{i},12,10);
 a{i} = a{i}';
 a{i} = a{i}(:,1:10);

end
```

There are 10 text file in the folder each of which contain a random matrix containing integer numbers 0 to 2 and name of each text file starts with "test_file_num_" and in a{i} I have the matrix which is 10x10 matrix. Now I want to represent the a{i} matrix as an image or graph or anything but to have something which would show the contents the matrix in a different color. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data in your file is structured, meaning has tabs or spaces between the numbers you can directly use `importdata` to load your data into a matrix. After that, you can use `imagesc` to produce the image. To assign the colors you can change the colormap using the `colormap` function. So your code would look something like this:

```
% Example data
A = floor(3*rand(10)); 
% Change colormap with just 3 colors (Red,Green,Blue)
cmap = [1 0 0;0 1 0;0 0 1];
figure; imagesc(A); colormap(cmap); colorbar;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think I can model my thing in the order you mentioned and get the proper result. Thanks

Comment: I am only confused with the purpose of the cmap matrix that you used.

Comment: I used the cmap matrix to force using only 3 colors, since you mentioned that you only have values of 0,1 and 2 in your data. See [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) for more information. The code above will work even without using the 3x3 matrix that I chose to use. In fact, I suggest that you try it yourself by using `colormap('jet')` in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `imagesc` function.

But you need to use `str2num` before since you are reading your numbers as chars.

i.e.:

```
imagesc(str2num(a{i});
```

If you want to read the file as numbers straight away, you should do:

```
fid = fopen(f);
a{i} = fscanf(fid,'%u',inf);
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but there is an error when I am trying to use the imagesc function

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for your reply. I am able to get the output but there is problem you see. The contents of the matrix is something like 
a{i }= {0102012;0011020;1222210.....} and when I am using the imagesc then I am seeing a strip of different colours. I just want to see the each of the matrix contents in different colours.

Comment: It seems `fileread` is giving you a cell array. Have you tried [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html)?

Comment: HI!
I have tried load and fopen with fscanf but I am getting the matrix not in number but in exponential term which I am not getting in fileread. I dont know why that is happening

Comment: It's probably because there are either really large or really small numbers in your matrix. This really isn't an issue. It's just the representation of the number.