# MATLAB: how to set colors in matrix

Tags: matlab, colors, matrix

I have a matrix N*N, with three different values, for example 0, 0.5, 1.
How can i print to the screen an image, which each value represent a different color?
Important: the matrix is a loop so the values may change (i want to print the matrix every iteration).

I tried to use colormap, it worked fine if all the three values were in the matrix,
but when one or two values only remain, the colors were changed.

How I want it to work: matrix with values 0, 0.5, 1 prints to the screen a matrix which each cell contains 0 colored black, 0.5 colored green, 1 colored yellow.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There was a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347792/images-from-matrix-in-matlab/14348724#14348724) a few days ago along the same lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create your own colormap that has only three possible values:

```
a = [1 0.5 0;1 .5 0;0.5 0 1];
b = [1 0 1;1 1 0;0 0 1];
cmap = [0,0,0;0,1,0;1,1,0];
clims = [0 1];
imagesc(a,clims); colormap(cmap);
imagesc(b,clims); colormap(cmap);
```

a gives:

[image: a]

b gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks that works pretty good, but still there's something bad.
If the matrix is all ones, or zeros, or any other number, i get a green printed matrix, and not the color i wanted it.
For a full of zeros matrix i want to get black matrix, but instead the output is green.
Do you know what to do?

Comment: a = [0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0];
b = [1 1 1;1 1 1;1 1 1];
cmap = [0,0,0;0,1,0;1,1,0];
imagesc(a); colormap(cmap);
imagesc(b); colormap(cmap);
I want a to be all black, and b to be all yellow
instead i get both of them green

Comment: do ``clims = [0 1]; imagesc(a,clims);``

Answer (score 0):

I would try maybe imagsec.  Or any other scaling for the colors.  Start with gray scale.  RGB will be alittle more complex